# Beraita of Rabbi Ishmael

Tags: hermeneutics

According to [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talmudical_hermeneutics#Detailed_rules):

> There is a dispute regarding the thirteen principles: Either the kal va-chomer is unique among the thirteen rules in that it may be applied by anyone in any circumstance in which it logically applies and the remaining twelve rules may only be applied with a tradition of application descending from Moses (or another authoritative legal board of the era) or all thirteen except a gezerah shava are open to all and only the latter is restricted in its application.

Where can the details of this "dispute" be found?